# Expectation and Variance of a Sequence Appearing

Tags: sequences-and-series, expectation, variance

Let X1, X2, . . . be a sequence of i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables taking value 1 with probability p. Denote by T1,1 the ﬁrst time the sequence 1, 1 appears:

T1,1 = min{n ∈ N : Xn− 1 = Xn = 1}.

Find E[T1,1] and Var(T1,1)

I solved E[T1,1] by conditioning on X1.

E[T1,1] = E[T1,1 | X1 = 1]P(X1 = 1) + E[T1,1 | X1 = 0]P(X1 = 0)

I know that E[T1,1 | X1 = 1] = E[T1,1 | X1 = 1, X2 = 1]P(X2 = 1) + E[T1,1 | X1 = 1, X2 = 0]P(X2 = 0) = 2(1/2) + (2 + E[T1,1])(1/2)

I also know that E[T1,1 | X1 = 0] = 1 + E[T1,1]

Therefore, E[T1,1] = (1+(2+E[T1,1])(1/2)) + (1+E[T1,1])(1/2)
so E[T1,1] = (3/2) + (3/4)(E[T1,1]). Hence, E[T1,1] = 6.

How do I go about solving for Var(T1,1)?

Comment: You can think of it as a discrete time Markov chain with states $\{start, 1, 11\}\leftrightarrow \{a,b,c\}$.  Let $T_a,T_b,T_c$ be the random times to get to state $c$ given we start in $\{a,b,c\}$, respectively, and note that $T_c=0$. So then $E[T_a]=E[(1+T_a)](1-p) + E[(1+T_b)]p$ and so on. Solving these equations with $p=1/2$ indeed gives $E[T_a]=6$. Similarly, $E[T_a^2] = E[(1+T_a)^2](1-p)+E[(1+T_b)^2]p$ and so on.

Comment: I understand your approach. How can I go about solving $E[(1+ $T_a$ )^2]$ and $E[(1+ $T_b$ )^2]$ ?

Comment: You can just expand them and solve.  $E[(X+Y)^2] = E[X^2] + 2E[XY] + E[Y^2]$.